# 3 related tables with a relation table in between for 2 input and 1 output

Tags: sql, relation

I have 3 tables

- **EVENTS** with 2 columns : id , event-name
- **RELATION** with 2 columns : event_id, cat_id
- **CATEGORY** with 2 columns : id, cat_name

here is my Data :

```
[EVENT]
id           event-name
--------------------
1            dance
2            walk
3            run

[RELATION]
event_id     cat_id
--------------------
1            1
1            2
2            1
3            3

[CATEGORY]
id           cat_name
---------------------
1            slow
2            fast
3            very fast
```

I want the EVENT name (in that case '*dance*') content the CATEGORY *slow* AND *fast*

What i tried :

```
Select * from EVENT e
left join RELATION r on e.id = r.event_id
left join CATEGORY c on r.cat_id = c.id
where c.cat_name = "slow" and c.cat_nam = "fast"
```

Comment: You forgot to include [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com). Please update your question.

Comment: It is, 1,1 and 1,2 in your relation table does this

Comment: what i tried doesn't give me the right result

Comment: i tried so many combinaison.. i'm not sur if it was my first attempt or the 10010101011th

Answer (score 1):

You want the events that have both.  Try this:

```
select e.event_name
from event e join
     relation r
     on e.id = r.event_id join
     category c
     on c.id = r.cat_id
group by e.event_name
having max(case when cat_name = 'slow' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when cat_name = 'fast' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
SELECT event_name
FROM event e
JOIN relation r      ON e.id = r.event_id
LEFT JOIN category c ON r.cat_id = c.id
WHERE cat_name='slow'
  AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
 FROM relation r
 JOIN category c ON r.cat_id=c.id
WHERE r.event_id = e.id
      AND c.cat_name='fast');
```

Comment: @Hète.ca . . . Feel free to upvote and accept answers that solve your problems.